# Azure Data Lake Analytics add Powershell API

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-data-lake

in Azure portal is option to Resubmit existing job.

[image: Azure portal interface for ADLA jobs]

Is it possible to do this via powershell?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the following using Azure PowerShell should do what you want:

```
$job = Get-AdlJob -Account <accountName> -JobId <jobId>

Submit-AdlJob -Account <accountName> -Name $job.Name -Script $job.Properties.Script -DegreeOfParallelism $job.DegreeOfParallelism -Priority $job.Priority
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!